# Preparing Accelerometer Data for SVM

Tags: c#, machine-learning, classification, svm, accelerometer

I am trying to classify activities by feeding the acceleration data from my phone into a SVM, which I'm implementing in C# with Accord. The problem is that I don't know how to prepare the data.

One of the Problems is that the SVM seems to only take 2 dimensional Input, but the data I get has 3 Dimensions of course. Do I have to transform the Data somehow first?

The second Problem I have is that I get the data like following:

```
1       x:1502      y:2215      z:2153  
1       x:1667      y:2072      z:2047  
1       x:1611      y:1957      z:1906  
2       x:1904      y:2367      z:2034  
2       x:1905      y:2375      z:2023  
2       x:1892      y:2379      z:2027
```

But I can't classify an activity by one row, since that is only a snapshot, only one frame while the activity is performed. So my guess is that it should look more something like this:

```
1 {x:1502 y:2215 z:2153}, {x:1667 y:2072 z:2047}, {x:1611 y:1957 z:1906}            
2 {x:1904 y:2367 z:2034}, {x:1905 y:2375 z:2023}, {x:1892 y:2379 z:2027}
```

And then again, how can i feed this kind of data to my SVM?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Since this question is not about a specific programming problem (and not even about C#), I suggest you better ask this at http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, it is called a sequence in classification. 
To do that you can use  Hidden Markov Classifier or Hidden Conditional Random Field Learning or a Dynamic Time Warp Support Vector Machine.

See [Accord.net wiki](https://github.com/accord-net/framework/wiki/Classification) section "Sequence classification"

Comment: While this link may answer the question, link only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)